# Add images via Push Notification Service?

Tags: cocoa-touch, sqlite, iphone-sdk-3.0, push-notification

I have a content app and would like to notify users of new content using Apple Push Notification Service, bypassing the now very long App Store submissions.  Once the user receives the notification, a download update button will become enabled.  The user will download an sql file plus images from my website.  The sql file will execute insert statements and the images will download to the disk.

I currently load content (strings and bundle image references) into a UIWebView. Images are displayed as part of the content.  How would I execute the sql file to insert new content?   Then, would I also need to start referencing images on disk rather than from the bundle, which is where I put images while using App Store update submissions?

For the sql file, I can probably run some event based code once the download is complete.  But then the read only database needs to be reloaded for new content to be seen.  Would the user have to restart the app?

Answer (score 0):

As you said the database is read-only to your app, I would just have the APN trigger a download of a new database file and write it to disk instead of having to execute SQL statements to modify an existing db.  (Unless your database is very large and you're only making a small change, when the download size would be a consideration).

In any case, if you are loading the database from the bundle it will be read-only so you can't execute insert statements on it - you will need to make a writable copy.  Having the update process replace this copy in its entirety means you don't have to worry about the SQL executing correctly on each device.  e.g. what happens if the app terminates mid-insert?

Similarly for images, your life would be easier if they were copied to a writable images directory on first launch rather than loaded from the bundle so you always look in the same place for them and don't care whether or not there's been an update.  Just make sure you clean up anything that's no longer required after an update so you're not eating more of the user's storage than you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do so.

- you add some custom field in your push notification payload, in my case,
  the 'msgId' can the field you need.

  ```
  $body = array();
  $body['device_tokens'] = str_replace(' ', '', $_REQUEST["Token"]);
  $body['msgId'] = $MP_ID;
  $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $alertShort);
  $payload = json_encode($body);
  ```
- send the payload to APN server (sandbox server/official server, depends on your situation)
- add the code to receive APN

  ```
      -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        NSLog(@"I got notification");

        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(handleRemoteNotification:) toTarget:self withObject:userInfo];
       }


  - (void)handleRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber++;// = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];

        if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"msgId"]) {
            iRetrievingAPNMessage++;
            NSString *msgId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[userInfo objectForKey:@"msgId"]];
            NSMutableString *theURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            [theURL appendFormat:@"http://yourDATAFeedPROGRAM.php?msgID=%@",msgId];

            MIPFileConnection *APNMsgConnection = [[MIPFileConnection alloc] initWithTargetURL:theURL useCache:NO];
            APNMsgConnection.delegate = self;
            [APNMsgConnection start];

            NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
            do {
            } while ((iRetrievingAPNMessage > 0) &&
                     [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
            NSLog(@"done");
        }
        [pool release];
    }

    - (void)updateDB:(NSDictionary *)msgDic {
        // do anything to update your sql db.
        // ATTENTION, the files located in bundle cannot be replaced.
        // so you need to duplicate your sql into cache/document path.
        // then you can update it successfully.
    }


    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLFileConnection *)connection {
        CFPropertyListRef plist = CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDataRef)connection.receiveData, kCFPropertyListImmutable, NULL);

            if (plist) {
                NSDictionary *tmpDic = (NSDictionary *)plist;

                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateDB:) withObject:[tmpDic copy] waitUntilDone:NO];

                [tmpDic release];
            }
            iRetrievingAPNMessage--;
    }
  ```

I used pseudo code in "updateDB", and fake URL, please replace it with your testing web URL. The above action works, I did it ok. But I cannot force the notification to show image when my app is in background.